# Observer Pattern ASP.NET Pages

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I am working on a project whereby I am trying to push updates to the master page in the website.

I have implemented the observer pattern and initialised the relevant class in the global asax under application.

I run 2 copies of the site say page copy A & page copy B I am trying to fire an event whereby when I click on A the event fires and all my page instances are updated at the moment only A is updated.

Is it possible where I can cause multiple instances to update? such as in a chatroom?

Should I use a mediator pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please post some relevant code.

Comment: I believe the op is trying to implement a broad cast system for his website that say a service administrator could send out a message informing all users that the website is going down for maintenance.

Comment: I think he wants to push updates to all pages that are looking at the same set of data and have those pages immediately "know" it has been pushed instead of using polling on those pages to see if data has changed.  Kind of between listening and polling or maybe something else.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for your replies. As Johnny stated. I am trying to push updates to all of the pages. I could just put a timer on the page and poll but it would be more effecient to push the data via event args when it is updated.

Comment: Do you know if it could be related to running on different treads. Does the Application & session run on different treads?

Comment: curious if this helps: http://weblogs.asp.net/istofix/archive/2008/01/31/implementing-observer-pattern.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the [Comet Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).  This allows your client pages to open long-running HTTP Queries to your website.  However, I don't recommend using this pattern as it is not very scalable.

HTML 5 allows you to open a socket connection from the browser with [Web Sockets](http://onepixelahead.com/2010/04/30/html5-web-sockets-example/) that is [pretty well supported by modern browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29#Related_specifications).  This allows you to open a socket connection to your server to allow you to inform clients when updates are available.

You could also use Flash or Silverlight to accomplish this.